# /locate command gives incorrect coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently tried a seed that should have had a woodland mansion close to spawn, but after looking for it for several hours, I gave up and used `/locate`. It gave me coordinates that fit what I saw in the seed showcase, but the mansion was most definitely not there.

I went into spectator mode and found a large mineshaft right below (which was also mentioned in the seed video; everything but the mansion lined up) but when I tried `/locate Mineshaft` I got coordinates extremely far away.

I have used locate successfully in other worlds without re-launching minecraft, and I was definitely in 1.11 every time I loaded this world. Other than this oddity the world doesn't seem corrupt or anything.

Am I somehow using `/locate` wrong? Or is this a problem with `/locate`/my world/both? Is it relevant that I was on peaceful difficulty?

Comment: What was the seed?

Comment: Did you disable structure generation?

Comment: UniversalElectricity I certainly didn't intentionally disable structure generation, and if I had done it by accident then the mineshaft wouldn't have spawned, right?

@HarounMohamed-Fakier the seed was -4589128118707775879

Comment: I checked the seed, used /locate Mansion, went to the coordinates 216 64 536 and found a mansion... And I think it's the same, as there is a mineshaft beneath it. It might have been a bug or you maybe you accidentally used 1.10 in the creation after all

Comment: @QunSyBer yeah those are the coordinates, and I remade the world and it generated this time... weird, I know I can't have been in 1.10, I didn't change anything between creating the world and using /locate...

Answer (score -1):

From what I've seen in the other answers here, it seems to have been a one-off thing. Since you say you generated the world in 1.11, I will assume that version is not the issue. It could well be a world generation bug, as arise from time to time. Try perfectly replicating the conditions for the world creation and when you tried using /locate. If it happens again, post the exact circumstances here. Also report the issue [here](https://bugs.mojang.com). If it doesn't repeat, then forget about it. It may be fixed later.